# Macbook Pro - 2014 - SM0512F SSD high io wait

Tags: 14.04, ssd, macbook-pro

I have recently installed a Macbook Pro with Kubuntu.
When I test it under OS X I do not see any issues with performance - but running Ubuntu causes a constant io wait time of about 20% if I use a web-browser - or install anything. The disk load shows less than a MB/s while the utilisation of the disk is up at 100%.

I checked how to update the FW of the SSD - without much real info. I tried a fix with the low power perl module - no difference.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Ubuntu - 14.04 LTS

Thanks,
Marcus